# Is it possible to add a JavaScript variable into JQuery .html() statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

bit of an odd question but is it possible to add a variable in the middle of a JQuery .html statement.

IE can I do something like.

```
var x = 150;

$("#sandbox").html("<div id='toannimate" + x + "' style='width:100px;'></div>");
```

I want to create a div with a new name that I just created. So I would have a loop and each time it added .html the new div id would be toannimate1, toannimate2, toannimate3, etc.

Or if I wanted to define the absolute position of that div could I set the x pos to a number from a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, have you tried? That seems correct. jQuery _is_ JavaScript, and `html()` is a JavaScript function.

Comment: Yes.  The string is fully evaluated before the function html executes (logically at least).  Like most languages, all parameters are evaluated before being passed to functions in Javascript (at least I'm 99% sure here... but blanket statements like that are dangerous...).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your line of code is totally valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exact syntax you used, or you can use a more verbose approach of creating an element and then setting it as the html of the other..

```
var x = 150;
var element = $('<div/>', {
        id:'toannimate' + x,
        width: '100px'
    });

$("#sandbox").html( element );
```

Comment: Hi, could you share a link to where I can read more about this style of notation? If you try to do things like add background-color#FF0000 it does not like that.

Comment: @user1944367, You can read about it at http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2 It is mainly for passing tag attributes, but if a jquery method exists with the same name it is used instead. that is why `width` works. for passing styles directly use `css: {'background-color':'#ff0000'}`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, what you have would work perfectly fine. You can create a loop of however many you want like so:

```
var x = 3;

for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    $("#sandbox").html("<div id='toannimate" + x + "' style='width:100px;' />");
}
```

Giving you toannimate1, toannimate2, toannimate3